# iPhone X Navigation Bar Back Button Issue with UnderLine

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

How to resolve following issue?

1. Navigation bar back button come with underline for only iPhone X layout.
2. This is not coming in other devices.
3. I did not used any code for adding underline.I just used one navigation controller with UI view controller.

Please find attached image for know more about this..
[image: Navigation bar back button image]

Comment: Do you have „Button shapes” enabled? You can check it here : Settings app > General > Accessibility > Button shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have copy the @Losiowaty commented on my question...

Thanks to @Losiowaty ..

Do you have „Button shapes” enabled?

You can check it here : Settings app > General > Accessibility > Button shapes.